# android textview background resized after creating another object

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

Introduction:
I have a problem about the textview background, I have a mind map application using textviews to link the node up, however, sometimes when I create a node under it's parent, the node's background will resized like this:

The capture of the app:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/5lhakzff3/]

the central topic and the blank node should have text inside it, but after creating nodes(textview) by long click, the object become resized, here is my code of creating node:

```
   builder.setItems(editNodeNode, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  if (which == 0){
                      new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Enter your nodes here")
                    .setMessage("Content")
                    .setView(input)

                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("WrongCall") public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            ((ViewGroup)input.getParent()).removeView(input);
                            String value = input.getText().toString(); 
                            NodeTextView node = myGenerator.createTV(value, c);
                            node.setPriority(currentPriority+1);

                            Log.d("success",node.myContent);


                        //node.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|CENTER_VERTICAL);
                        rl.addView(node);

                        NodeTextView parent = TextViewGenerator.editnode;
                        parent = getMotionXY();



                        parentID = currentID;
                        node.setParentID(TextViewGenerator.editnode.TMPid);

                        //set currentID to new create node ID
                        int newCurrent = node.getTmpID();
                        currentID = newCurrent;


                        for (int i = 0;i < tvArrayList.size();i++){
                            if (tvArrayList.get(i).getTmpID() == parentID){
                                NodeTextView parentObject = tvArrayList.get(i);
                                Log.d("parentid", parentID+"");
                                parentObject.setChildID(newCurrent);
                                Log.d("child", newCurrent+"");
                            } 
                        }

                        rl.invalidate();
                        tvArrayList.add(node);


                        for(int i =0; i< tvArrayList.size() -1 ;i++){
                            NodeTextView locationObj = tvArrayList.get(i);


                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                        params.setMargins(locationObj.getLocation()[0]- 50, locationObj.getLocation()[1] -50, 
                                locationObj.getLocation()[2], locationObj.getLocation()[3]);
                        params.height =150;
                        params.width = 200;
                        Log.d("obj height",+locationObj.TMPid +","+locationObj.getHeight() );
                        Log.d("obj width",+locationObj.TMPid +","+locationObj.getWidth() );
                        locationObj.setHeight(150);
                        locationObj.setWidth(200);
                        locationObj.setLayoutParams(params);

                        }

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                                params.setMargins(node.getLocation()[0] + 300, node.getLocation()[1] +300, 
                                        node.getLocation()[2], node.getLocation()[3]);
                                params.height =150;
                                params.width = 200;
                                node.setLayoutParams(params);




                        for(int i=0;i<tvArrayList.size();i++){
                            Log.d("tvArray"+i,"id: "+tvArrayList.get(i).getTmpID()+" txt: "+tvArrayList.get(i).myContent);
                        }

                        testLine = (TestDrawing) findViewById(R.id.drawingview);
                        int lineID = testLine.drawLine(parent.getX(),parent.getY() , node.getX(), node.getY());
                        node.addLine("tail", lineID);
                        parent.addLine("head", lineID);
                        testLine.invalidate();
                        //setContentView(testLine);



                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Do nothing.
                        ConvertToJson myConverter = new ConvertToJson(tvArrayList);
                        myConverter.JsonGenerator();

                    }
                }).show();
```

please help me!Thank you so much for help!

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: i want to resize the green textview so that the text can be shown in that textview, the problem sometimes is not appear but sometimes does. I found that all answer in google can't help....

Comment: this green text view is a vertical do you want it in this way ?

Comment: also can you please share me us a photo which clearly describe what you want it to be

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/wioaoghh3/ should be like this

Comment: good so now  tell me are these things dynamic according to their positions or they are static , I mean are those line would move or they are static.

Comment: the lines are dynamic - this is a mind map application to show node, the node can be moved and the lines will follow it by setXY.When i create a new textview with not setting layoutparams, all the nodes will be shown in the left corner, but the size of textview will not be resize like that; 
i use a for loop to set margin of layoutparams, and this problem occur.
Thank you for trying to answering my question!